# ?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest when using mvc Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I use MVC 3.

With the following code:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("CreateUser", "Administration",
            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", 
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "DialogContainer", 
            OnComplete = "OpenDialog();" })
```

I get a javascript error when i click the link:

> GET> http://myWebsite.com/Administration/Administration?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
>   404 (Not Found) jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2

I the function designated for "OnComplete" is fired and the dialog pops out but not content is return from the controller.

Can you help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 404 error tells you that the page /Administration/Administration does not exist. That is the action method **Administration** does not exist on the AdministrationController.

Check that the action method "Administration" exists.

The overload you are using is [ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493106%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

The query string X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest is not required to solve this issue.

By default Microsoft Ajax and jQuery use a header to signify that a request originates in JavaScript. MVC makes allowances for the fact that not all environments allow custom headers (X-Requested-With is a custom error) to be sent with a request, by allowing the header value to be sent as a Query String parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much .. i missed that .. i thought that it was action, controller ... and missed the administration\administration url .. thank you !!!